# pylucene installation make test fails

Tags: python, ubuntu, lucene, pylucene

I'm following this [blog](https://medium.com/@michaelaalcorn/how-to-use-pylucene-e2e2f540024c) to install pylucene on Ubuntu.

I installed all the required files. At the last step which is executing the following scripts:

```
make
make test
make install
```

I get an error when I run the second line `make test`.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f39aaaae12c, pid=15210, tid=0x00007f39afa31740
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_231-b11) (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.231-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x6d812c]  jni_RegisterNatives+0x7c
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/bg/pylucene-8.1.1/core or core.15210
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/bg/pylucene-8.1.1/hs_err_pid15210.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
xargs: /home/bg/py3/bin/python: terminated by signal 6
Makefile:428: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 125
```

Comment: did you figure out why this was happening? I am getting a similar error for ```test3/test_PrefixQuery.py```. I don't really know what I am supposed to be looking for in the log file either. Any help will be great. Thanks.

Comment: No @PSK .. I gave up at that time and changed the whole plan.